# How to get the parent control from an assigned context menu using C#?

Tags: .net, forms, listview, contextmenu

I have a few listview controls on a windows form and i've assigned a common contextmenustrip to them all using the properties grid in VS2005.

Now when a selection is made from the contextmenu in any listview, is there a way i can get the correct hosting control of the raised menu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol.aspx)